# Keeping track of purchases on server my rather than iTunesConnect

Tags: mysql, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm developing an app, where there are over 700+ potential purchases.

What I wanted to do is setup a single tier1 key on iTunesConnect and reuse the same key for all purchases, thus using my database/server to keep track of what was purchased; this meaning the key would give you a credit of some sort, then you would select the content you would like to unlock and the credit is then spent serverside until you purchase another from the IAS.

The user would obviously have to register and login through the app, so all this could be tracked.

Is this a good practice? I also wanted to avoid using a local plist file to guard against jailbroken iphones and hackers of the sort.

Am I on the right track?